# Minimaslistic Telnet Library - Read output to the end

Tags: c#, telnet

I am working on a project where I should run commands on Unix servers and get the full output of those commands. For this purpose, I am using Minimaslistic Telnet Library from code project (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library). For now, everything works fine excepting the output, because I want to read it all, not just a portion of it. I can have commands that may take long time. Here is the read output method in the Minimaslistic Telnet Library :

```
public string Read()
{
    if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return null;
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    do
    {
        ParseTelnet(sb);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeOutMs);
    } while (tcpSocket.Available > 0);
    return sb.ToString();
}


void ParseTelnet(StringBuilder sb)
{
    while (tcpSocket.Available > 0)
    {
        int input = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
        switch (input)
        {
            case -1 :
                break;
            case (int)Verbs.IAC:
                // interpret as command
                int inputverb = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                if (inputverb == -1) break;
                switch (inputverb)
                {
                    case (int)Verbs.IAC: 
                        //literal IAC = 255 escaped, so append char 255 to string
                        sb.Append(inputverb);
                        break;
                    case (int)Verbs.DO: 
                    case (int)Verbs.DONT:
                    case (int)Verbs.WILL:
                    case (int)Verbs.WONT:
                        // reply to all commands with "WONT", unless it is SGA (suppres go ahead)
                        int inputoption = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                        if (inputoption == -1) break;
                        tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)Verbs.IAC);
                        if (inputoption == (int)Options.SGA )
                            tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WILL:(byte)Verbs.DO); 
                        else
                            tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WONT : (byte)Verbs.DONT); 
                        tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)inputoption);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                sb.Append( (char)input );
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This code sample reads output, but asynchronously, I need it to **wait** for output before quitting. Is there any idea about changing the code to meet my requirements? Thank you!

Comment: This is not a problem with the Telnet protocol, but the underlying protocol TCP. TCP is a streaming protocol, there is no beginning and no end. How will TCP (or Telnet) know when the output from some specific "command" is done? They cant, instead you have to parse the data you read on a higher level to try and determine when the data you receive is done. That is, you have to call `Read` in a loop, and parse the data to determine the end.

Comment: I see, so can I reimplement the same functionality using another protocol that supports synchronous reading ?

Comment: Please is there any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Joachim, calling the read in a loop and parsing for the end out the output is the best approach.  Unfortunately for me, my output didn't have a standardize ending for each command I executed. Instead, I used the read timeout of the stream to approximate the end of the output (I realize this isn't perfect).  I set a higher initial timeout to allow the data to start flowing, and then lowered the timeout to find the end of the output.  It looks something like this:

```
static string ReadFromStream(int initialTimeout, int subsequentTimeout)
    {
        // Initialize output
        string output = null;

        try
        {
            // Set initial read timeout -- This is needed because occasionally
            // it takes a while before data starts flowing
            stream.ReadTimeout = initialTimeout;

            while (stream.CanRead)
            {
                // Read bytes in from stream
                readBuffer = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                stream.Read(readBuffer, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);

                // Convert the bytes to string and save to output
                output = string.Format("{0}{1}", output, Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer).Trim());

                // Set subsequent read timeout
                stream.ReadTimeout = subsequentTimeout;
            }
        }
        // Since we don't know when the output will end, we wait for, and catch the timeout
        catch (IOException) { }

        // Return output
        return output;
    }
```